# Prencher toda área do ecrã através das células da GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Eu possuo um projecto que possui uma GridView com várias células e necessito que as células que compõem a Gridview preencham toda área útil do ecrã do SmartPhone.
Com o seguinte código XML não funcionou:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e4c5c5">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="7" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CelulasAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<DiasMesApoio> arrayListDiasMes;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    // Construtor:
    public CelulasAdapter(Context context, List<DiasMesApoio> arrayListDiasMes, int width, int height) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayListDiasMes = arrayListDiasMes;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListDiasMes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayListDiasMes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View viewLayout;
        ViewHolder viewholder;

        if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_celulas_gridview, null);

            viewholder = new ViewHolder();

            viewholder.textView1 = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            viewLayout.setTag(viewholder);

            convertView = viewLayout;

        } else {

            viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            viewLayout = convertView;
        }

        viewLayout.setMinimumHeight(GridViewActivity.height/6);

        DiasMesApoio diasMesApoio = arrayListDiasMes.get(position);

        viewholder.textView1.setText(String.valueOf(diasMesApoio.getDia()));

        return viewLayout;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando um adapter personalizado? Ou como você está adicionando os itens.

Comment: estou usando uma Classe Adapter para construir os itens da GridView: gridView.setAdapter(new CelulasAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList));

Comment: Eu teste aqui com seu XML,  e se adicionar os itens dinamicamente sem usar um adapter personalizado,  tudo funciona como esperado, ocupa a tela toda.  Você já tentou assim, para testar? Talvez seja algum problema com o tamanho dos seus itens personalizados que você usa na classe CelulasAdapter.

Comment: Meu layout para os itens da GridView: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Dia"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#fefdba" />
    
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Podia-me mostrar o código que você utilizou para adicionar os itens dinamicamente sem adapter?

Comment: Não foi sem adapter, foi sem usar um adapter personalizado, como é o seu caso. Fiz assim:

`ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            adapter.add(i);
        }

        ((GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView2)).setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta, você tenta fazer pra ver o que dá. Usando seu Adapter Personalizado.

Comment: Tente essa solução:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11049803/4744158

Comment: Tentei a solução que me enviou, mas na minha Classe Adapter não consigo importar a Classe GridViewActivity? Podia-me ajudar?

Comment: A classe GridViewActivity é na verdade a sua acvitivy, onde você seta o adapter.  Você deve recuperar o tamanho da tela lá, botar em uma variável estática e publica,  antes de setar o adapter e depois, no seu adapter,  você recupera esse valor que você obteve na sua activity.

Comment: Certo. Mas as "linhas view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);" e
"view.setMinimumHeight(GridViewActivity.height/6);" tem de ser inseridas na Classe Adapter e a minha classe Adapter é um novo ficheiro?

Comment: Exatamente,  se não souber como fazer,  edite sua resposta e adicione o adapter.

Comment: Luiz, adicionei a minha Classe Adapter em cima na pergunta e na linha "viewLayout.setMinimumHeight(GridViewActivity.height/6);" não consigo importar a Classe GridViewActivity...

Comment: Como eu já disse,  GridViewActivity você tem que substituir pelo nome da sua acvitivy, onde você seta o adapter.

Comment: Ok. Não tinha percebido. Funcionou mais ou menos, ou seja, criou um espaçamento horizontal enorme entre os itens mas ocupou todo ecrã... Vou tentar arranjar uma forma de colocar o layout mais bonito...

Comment: Luiz, adicionei uma nova imagem para mostrar como agora ficam os itens da GridView. Não encontro uma forma de colocar o tamanho do espaçamento horizontal dos itens todo igual, ou seja, ficar igual ao seu espaçamento vertical! Consegue-me ajudar?